# formating a numeric value in php paypal payments

Tags: php, paypal

Hie guys can point out my mistake, um trying to parse the amount to be payed to the paypal sdk for payments, but um getting this error "Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Subtotal is not a valid numeric value' "

```
 $pay_amount = $_GET['qtn'];
    $pay_amount= number_format((float)$pay_amount, 2, '.', '');

    //Payer
    $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

    $details->setShipping('0.00')
            ->setTax('5.00')
            ->setSubtotal($pay_amount);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php Number format returns a string, edit; https://3v4l.org/lg5D2

Comment: Any particular reason why you need two decimals on amount?

Comment: so how to i make it to be valid when parsing it to setSubTotal as argument?

Comment: Remove number_format. Why do you need the decimals? If there is a decimal it will be there, if there is none, it will be an integer

Comment: i want to represent it as money when i pass it to setSubTotal, or do i just pass it without formatting it first to decimals?

Comment: Whatever setsubtotal needs to do, it needs a number, not a string. If you later need to output the number then you can use number_format()

Answer (score 0):

Number format is used to format a number for **output**.
You don't need to format numbers when you still need to do math to them, PHP will handle the numbers.

See here;

```
$pay_amount = 3.5+1.3;
Var_dump($pay_amount); // float 4.8

$pay_amount = 3+1;
Var_dump($pay_amount); // int 4
```

https://3v4l.org/JBF88